# GE dishwasher (model: GSD03230Z01WW) does not drain

Tags: dishwasher

My GE dishwasher won’t drain. Washer is washing, but doesn’t drain. Ending the washing cycle,  there’s not hum.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Any reason why you aren't guessing that the pump is bad?

Comment: I couldn't find info on the model number you listed. Could you double check it? Also, some machines have separate drain pumps, and others use a switch that reverses the wash pump to allow for draining. The switch or pump could be bad, even the timer itself could be bad. Lots of could be's.